# checkboxes checked when mysql row = true?

Tags: php, javascript

I am making a page where the user can set there own settings. I need a loop to check the checkbox when the row is true and to be unchecked when its not. How would I go about this? in php/javascript.

Thanks

```
echo "<form method=\"post\">";

echo "<table>
<tr>
     <td>1</td>
      <td><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[]\"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[]\"></td>
</tr>


</table>";  
echo"<input name=\"update\" type=\"submit\" id=\"update\" value=\"Update\" method\"post\">";
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    // some code...

    $checked = '';
    if($row['setting_1'] === TRUE)
    {
          $checked = 'checked="checked"';
    }

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="setting_1" value="value_1" '.$checked.' />';

    // some code...

}
```

Comment: One more thing how can I add a loop to check the row?  I have these stored in an array like $settings[0]. can I do something like for i = 1 to 5 etc ? Thanks

Comment: do you store all of the settings in one field ? if not, what does it (the table) look like ? It might be better if you could post that as a new question, to keep things clean and tidy. (eg. one question for one specific problem)

Comment: I just wanted a different way to do the if check...but then the $checked would also have to be changed for each checkbox. Different fields

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you get a value from row and then while iterating do:

```
<input type="checkbox" <? if ($value==true) echo "checked=checked"; ?> />
```

PS. I just hope you are not expecting us to wrote here the entire whole code for you, right?

Comment: Should be checked="checked" or nothing, true/false isn't valid HTML.

Comment: No am not, just to get the idea of how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, add this:

```
 echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" ";
 if ( $value_which_should_be_true ) { echo "checked=\"checked\""; }
 echo "/>";
```

This uses the `checked` HTML attribute for checkboxes, which specifies the default state.

Comment: as stated above, this should be checked="checked"

Comment: D'oh! I'm used to HTML's plain "checked" and guessed. Tah.

Answer (score 0):

The `checked` attribute takes "checked" (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)), so I'd do something like:

`<input type="checkbox" <? if ($value == true) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />`

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
if ($value == true) { $checked = 'checked="checked"' };
echo '<input type="checked".$checked.' />;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my submit form I used

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="checked" <?php $row['checkbox'];?> />
```

wWhen I call the data from an update form or loop the above retrieves and the toggle works with every update or submission. Hope this makes sense or helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input <?php if (!(strcmp($row->value,1))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> name="ckeck" id="check" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It makes your answer more useful to more users if you add explanation to your post rather than just the code.